# How do I create a for loop to have a h1 repeat multiple times?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

How do I create an H1 tag with the text “Hello World”, and append it to the DOM and then Create a for-loop, repeat this process 10 times so that 10 H1’s with the text “Hello World” show up when the website is visited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You literally just need to combine a for loop with DOM manipulation:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    const ele = document.createElement("h1");
    ele.innerHTML = "Hello, world!";
    document.body.appendChild(ele);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you a bit more flexibility you can use the solution posted above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64699889/9818988) and wrap the code in a function. For example:

```
const makeElements = (elName, times) => {
for (let i = 0; i < times; i ++) {
    const ele = document.createElement(elName);
    ele.innerHTML = "Hello, world!";
    document.body.appendChild(ele);
 }
};
```

and then call the function when the document is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 makeElements('h1', 10);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const h1 = '<h1>Hello World!</h1>';
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  $('#container').append(h1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see a jquery tag on this question?

Comment: it would be the same principle without jquery, just a different mechanism for selecting the container to append the h1s.

Comment: Ok, well write that.